# Perl - Searching values in a log file and store/print them as a string.

Tags: string, perl, search

I would like to search values after a specific word (Current Value = ) in a log file, and makes a string with values.

vcs_output.log:  a log file

```
** Fault injection **
  Count = 1533
  0: Path = cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rcc_data_e[6]
  0: Current value = x
  1: Path = cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rs3_data_e[51]
  1: Current value = x
  2: Path = cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rs1_data_e[3]
  2: Current value = 1
  3: Path = cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.shft_alu_shift_out_e[18]
  3: Current value = 0
  4: Path = cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rs3_data_e[17]
  4: Current value = x
  5: Path = cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rs1_data_e[43]
  5: Current value = 0
  6: Path = cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rcc_data_e[38]
  6: Current value = x
  7: Path = cmp_top.iop.sparc0.exu.alu.byp_alu_rs2_data_e_l[30]
  7: Current value = 1
   .
   .
   .
```

If I store values after "Current value = ", then x,x,1,0,x,0,x,1. I ultimately save/print them as a string such as xx10x0x1.

Here is my code
code.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
##### Read input
open ( my $input_fh, '<', 'vcs_output.log' ) or die $!; 
chomp ( my @input = <$input_fh> );

my $i=0;
my @arr;
while (@input) {
    if (/Current value = /)
    $arr[i]= $input;  # put the matched value to array 
   }

}

## make a string from the array using an additional loop 

close ( $input_fh );
```

I think there is a way to make a string in one loop (or even not using a loop). Please advise me to make it. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do both that you ask for.

To build a string directly, just append to it what you capture in the regex

```
my $string;
while (<$input_fh>) 
{
    my ($val) = /Current\s*value\s*=\s*(.*)/;
    $string .= $val;
}
```

If the match fails then `$val` is an empty string, so we don't have to test.  You can also write the whole `while` loop in one line

```
$string .= (/Current\s*value\s*=\s*(.*)/)[0] while <$input_fh>;
```

but I don't see why that would be necessary.  Note that this reads from the filehandle, and line by line. There is no reason to first read all lines into an array.

---

To avoid (explicit) looping, you can read all lines and pass them through [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html), naively as

```
my $string = join '', 
    map { (/Current\s*value\s*=\s*(.*)/) ? $1 : () } <$input_fh>;
```

Since `map` needs a list, the filehandle is in *list context*, returning the list of all lines in the file. Then each is processed by code in `map`'s block, and its output list is then joined.

The trick `map { ($test) ? $val : () }` uses `map` to also do `grep`'s job, to filter -- the empty list that is returned if `$test` fails is flattened into the output list, thus disappearing. The "test" here is the regex match, which in the *scalar context* returns true/false, while the capture sets `$1`.

But, like above, we can return the first element of the list that match returns, instead of testing whether the match was successful. And since we are in `map` we can in fact return the "whole" list

```
my $string = join '', 
    map { /Current\s*value\s*=\s*(.*)/ } <$input_fh>;
```

what may be clearer here.

---

Comments on the code in the question

- the `while (@input)` is an infinite loop, since `@input` never gets depleted. You'd need `foreach (@input)` -- but better just read the filehandle, `while (<$input_fh>)`
- your regex does match on a line with that string, but it doesn't attempt to match the pattern that you need (what follows `=`). Once you add that, it need be captured as well, by `()`
- you can assign to the i-th element (which should be `$i`) but then you'd have to increment `$i` as you go. Most of the time it is better to just `push @array, $value`

Comment: You don't need the conditional expression. `my $string = join '', map { /Current\s*value\s*=\s*(\S+)/ } <$input_fh>` will work fine, because a non-matching regex returns an empty list in list context.

Comment: @Borodin  Yes, I've had that I think (the second example with `map`) -- I wanted to also show how to use a condition in `map`, for when it comes handy.  But your comment made me realize that I was taking the element only, which in `map` isn't needed (updated). Thank you.

Comment: @JaeyoungPark  Can you explain what you mean by "bits"? You are reading from a file and each `0,1,x` are _characters_ -- a byte each (at least).  Do you mean to split the string into 3-3-2 character pieces? Or to consider your 8-symbol result as a byte, encoding one of `0,1,x` per bit, and split that into 3-3-2 bits? (That may need other clarifications, and it may be better asked separately.) What does `x` mean then?

Comment: @zdim, each character is a bit in my case. I am reading a binary bit from a log file. 0 or 1, x is don't care bit so it can be either 0 or 1. There are 8 lines (and values) on a log file, and I would like to make three strings such as xx1, 0x0, and x1

Comment: @JaeyoungPark  Wait, let's clear this up. You show an ascii  file, and read it in normally, and the `1` and `0` in the file are stored in a _character_ each. Not a bit, but (likely) a byte. For all of them you get, as you say in the question, "_string such as `xx10x0x1`_".  The code clearly puts these in a string where each is a character (that's the intent I mean). Now, given that you need `0` and `1`, you _can_ represent them by a single bit instead. Is this what you want, to convert them into bits?

Comment: @JaeyoungPark  If you want to represent the eight of them (characters) in 3-3-2 groups (of bits), then what do you do with 3 bits? A string with a single character is a byte (say), so 8 bits. If you want them in separate variables the 3 bits can be padded (to 8, for a character). Or, they can _all_ be kept in a single byte, as a single character.  You can do this directly using `0bxx` notation and `oct`, by using a "scratch" character and flipping individual bits, or even using `vec` (etc).  But you'd need to explain what you want with those 3 bits.

Answer (score 1):

You can use capturing parentheses to grab the string you want:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @arr;
open ( my $input_fh, '<', 'vcs_output.log' ) or die $!; 
while (<$input_fh>) {
    if (/Current value = (.)/) {
        push @arr, $1;
    }
}
close ( $input_fh );
print "@arr\n";

__END__

x x 1 0 x 0 x 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep` and `perlre`
http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html
http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

If on a non-Unix environment then...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

open (my $fh, '<', "vcs_output.log");

chomp (my @lines = <$fh>);

# Filter for lines which contain string 'Current value'
@lines = grep{/Current value/} @lines;

# Substitute out what we don't want... leaving us with the 'xx10x0x1'
@lines = map { $_ =~ s/.*Current value = //;$_} @lines;
my $str = join('', @lines);

print $str;
```

Otherwise...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my $output = `grep "Current value" vcs_output.log | sed 's/.*Current value = //'`;

$output =~ s/\n//g;
print $output;
```